# Use unix_socket in mysql with host other than localhost

Tags: mysql

In order to replicate some script behavior on a test box I need to auth mysql with root via unix socket.

It works fine with sudo mysql, but when I do sudo mysql -h testhost I get:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I have added testhost to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost testhost
```

I have also updated mysql grants

```
    | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket USING '*59D9CEFB549F231CFA8634AC47153FD4F3CCC29F' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

And

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket USING '*59D9CEFB549F231CFA8634AC47153FD4F3CCC29F'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unix sockets" are not TCP/IP sockets. They are *always* limited to the current system only – it is not possible to connect to another system's socket over the network.

Because of that, the hostname `localhost` is special in MySQL and the client doesn't actually attempt to look up its IP address *at all*. And when you connect to it, you are not connecting to 127.0.0.1 nor ::1 – you're actually connecting to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` or some similar path.

If you want to imitate a network connection, run `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` or `mysql -h ::1`.

Network (TCP/IP) connections *cannot* use `IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket`, because they do not transfer the client's UID (especially not in any security-sensitive way). They must use passwords, X.509 certificates, or GSSAPI.